# What is the benefit of playing on 200cc?

Tags: mario-kart-tour

If you buy the gold pass in Mario Kart Tour you unlock access to 200cc.  I'm at the point where I've completed around 8 cups and still the 200cc option has never awarded a higher point bonus than 150cc.

Is the only point to 200cc so that you can complete the race faster or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

200cc is there just for an extra challenge, though the tracks aren't designed around it (for example, you can go out of bounds in Dino Dino Jungle just by launching off a blue ramp).

It can also be used to help you get better combos by reducing the time it takes to travel through barren areas, though it's possible to boost your combo time (time allowed between actions in a combo) enough that you can chain miniturbos endlessly. This can be done by choosing gliders that favor the track in question and levelling them up by getting repeats of it.

Comment: No, choosing the right glider will increase the time you have to perform another action without breaking your combo.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add to [inakilbss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/155852/inakilbss) answer that the experience you get from the race is higher, the more cc the race is.

So in the 200cc you would also earn more experience

Answer (score 1):

200cc is the fastest mode in Mario Kart Tour. One of the reasons the someone might want to play that mode is because it is more challenging. Your cart would be harder to handle compared to the other modes. You would have to use more drifts and/or lighter carts to make it around corners without hitting walls.

So if you want a more difficult game play on 200cc.

Comment: All karts go equally fast and turn equally well in this game.